# File Upload from MVC Application and stored in Web API Bin Folder

Tags: file-upload, dll, upload, image-uploading

I have a MVC Application (e.g. MVCApp1), I upload a file (e.g. example.dll) to my MVCApp1 via upload control. I need to store my example.dll to bin folder of  another application (e.g. WebAPIApp)

How can I do that and what should I write down in

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found my answer, may be useful for u

=======Web API CODE ================

public class UploadController : ApiController
    {

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        // Check whether the POST operation is MultiPart?
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
// Prepare CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider in which our multipart form
        // data will be loaded.
        string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            // Read all contents of multipart message into CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
            }

            // Send OK Response along with saved file names to the client.
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
}

// We implement MultipartFormDataStreamProvider to override the filename of File which
// will be stored on server, or else the default name will be of the format like Body-
// Part_{GUID}. In the following implementation we simply get the FileName from 
// ContentDisposition Header of the Request Body.
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

======================== Console Application Code===============

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            // Make sure to change API address
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:53798/");


            // Add first file content 
            var fileContent1 = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\Users\aisadmin\Desktop\Me\NF2202533167366.pdf"));
            fileContent1.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Sample.pdf"
            };

            // Add Second file content
            var fileContent2 = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\Users\aisadmin\Desktop\Sample.txt"));
            fileContent2.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Sample.txt"
            };

            content.Add(fileContent1);
            content.Add(fileContent2);

            // Make a call to Web API
            var result = client.PostAsync("/api/upload", content).Result;

            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]